# Displaying subplots

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, python-3.6, subplot

I am working my way through this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VavyFWb-r-8

I have this code which runs without error but it only displays the first plot. Actually, both plots are displayed but only the first one has bars and a title.  The second one is just empty.

If I display them separately they each work fine.  It is only when I try to use subplots that I run into the issue of the second one displaying empty.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
df6 = df[df.Sex == 'male'].Survived.value_counts().plot(kind='barh', ax=axs[0], title='Male Survivorship')
plt.show()
print(df6)
df7 = df[df.Sex == 'female'].Survived.value_counts().plot(kind='barh', ax=axs[1], title='Female Survivorship')
plt.show()
print(df7)
```

Comment: Remove the first `plt.show()`

Comment: That was it.  If you make your comment an answer I will vote it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `show()` before adding the second plot.

To get the needed result ie 2 subplots, You must remove the first call to `show()`

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

df6 = df[df.Sex == 'male'].Survived.value_counts().plot(kind='barh', ax=axs[0], title='Male Survivorship')

print(df6)

df7 = df[df.Sex == 'female'].Survived.value_counts().plot(kind='barh', ax=axs[1], title='Female Survivorship')

plt.show()

print(df7)
```

The above code can be used to making subplots as you need